# What licenses are users of 'Force.com' sites using?

Tags: community, licenses

We have a site, but not of 'Community' type (not a Digital Experience), but of 'Force.com' type - the one under Sites and Domains > Sites in UI. We've been using it without authentication - just a public access. Now, we want users to register and have their own accounts. What licenses are used for that purpose? Are they the same licenses as for Digital Experience? Users don't need much privileges - jus to access the history of their orders etc.
Thanks!

Comment: [Sites/Site.Com](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_sites.htm&type=5) and [Experience Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

Comment: You need Experience Cloud for that.