# Is it still possible to create self registration for Force.Com sites?

Tags: community, customer-community

Client needs self-registration feature for their community users. They have their community set up in old Sites (of force.com type). I don't see any option to set the self registration there. The Login Settings are disabled in Site settings page. I've red that this can be enabled under 'Customer Portal', but that section is not available to me, and was most likely  cancelled in 2013. I could move site to Digital Experience, and set the user self-reg there, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/410487/what-licenses-are-users-of-force-com-sites-using

Comment: 2 different questions

Comment: Thus "Almost".  The comments in the previous question apply to this one. Site/Site.Com licenses still exist but they've been deprecated and dead for a while now, only there because of legacy customers. Move to Experience Cloud.

Comment: Thanks for answer identigral. It's not the issue of licenses anymore - I could use customer community plus licenses. The question is about the option of user self-registration. It doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_external has the basic steps. If you're still stuck after going through this Trailhead, please edit your question and provide steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: thanks for help identigral. However, the trailhead instruction you shared, are for Digital Experiences, not Sites of Force.com type. I need to know how to set it up for Force.com Sites

Comment: Every Digital Experience Cloud has a Force.com Site.  You can have multiple experience clouds in your org and each will have its own Site.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm aware that Digital Experience can be accessed via Sites as well. Thing is - I have a Force.com site without Digital Experience